# System.Data.SqlClient Namespace for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ado.net

The exception says that there is a network related problem, or that the SQL server does not allow remote access, none of those are true.

Can it be that I'm trying to connect a MySQL server, and not MS SQL?

Thanks

Comment: can you show the connection string, wich you are using?

Comment: Are you doing something like this? http://bitdaddys.com/MySQL-ConnectorNet.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because the System.Data.SqlClient namespace is designed for Microsoft SQL Server, to connect to MySQL you will need to download and reference the MySQL .NET Connector http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/. You will then use the System.Data.MySqlClient namespace. Hope this helps.

Comment: Isn't `System.Data.MySqlClient` named `MySql.Data.MySqlClient` now?