# can't connect to mysql database with webapi

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, phpmyadmin

So I have zyxel server in my home. I made mySQL database using phpmyadmin. And I cannot reach this database using asp.net core webAPI.

I got System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException on my IRepository's method. Of course this is because the method is trying to get database data.

Connection string looks like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "DefaultConnection": "Server=(xxx.xxx.x.xx);Database=sensor;User=temp;Password=pwd;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I also have problems with connecting same db with python.

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` is for Microsoft SQL Server. If you want to connect to a MySQL database, you'll need to use a different library. Try looking on NuGet for an appropriate library.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue 1**

That connection string appears to be for SQL server. You need a MySql-specific connection string. I've always found [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) to be helpful in situations like this.

Here's the MySQL template that they provide:

> **Standard**
>
> Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
>
> **Specifying TCP port**
>
> Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
>   Pwd=myPassword;
>
> **Multiple servers**
>
> Use this to connect to a server in a replicated server configuration
>   without concern on which server to use.
>
> Server=serverAddress1, serverAddress2,
>   serverAddress3;Database=myDataBase; Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;

See https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/ for additional info.

**Issue 2**

Based on the error message that you provided, you're using a SQL data provider instead of a MySQL connector. Bottom line, you need a MySQL connector. You can download that [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

See this post for additional information: [System.Data.SqlClient Namespace for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764953/system-data-sqlclient-namespace-for-mysql)

Comment: @mason, you're absolutely right. I pushed submit too quickly. I've updated my answer. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: Hey, i've tried scafolding the db launched on my pc on localhost this time but i got "Build failed" message. Any clues?

Comment: @Luka, No, sorry. That's not enough info.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my problem by using [Pomelo's library](https://github.com/PomeloFoundation/Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql). Docs library didn't seem to work.