# Errors in SQL connection using PowerShell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am writing a script in PowerShell that opens an SQL database. I can connect to the DB using MySQL Workbench just fine using the same credentials and I can even use it on my .PHP local website. Just can't make it work on PowerShell.

I am using XAMPP for the DB btw.

Here is my code:

```
$dataSource = “localhost”
$user = “root”
$pwd = “”
$database = “sample_db”
$connectionString = “Server=$dataSource; Database=$database; user=$user; password=$pwd;”
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
$connection.Open()
```

I have 2 problems:

1. when $dataSource = “localhost”, it throws error "Login failed for user 'root'."
2. when $dataSource = “localhost,3306”, it throws error "Internal connection fatal error. Error state: 18"

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: `System.Data.SqlClient` is used for SQL server, it won't work with MySQL, you need to install and use the correct libraries for MySQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.Data.SqlClient Namespace for MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764953/system-data-sqlclient-namespace-for-mysql)

Comment: woah that was fast! thank you. I'l scour the web for the correct libraries.

Comment: you're right! I'm using the wrong library. I found the correct library here: https://michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-some-examples-to-use-a-mysql-database/

Comment: Good luck getting it working!